# How to keep textarea focus intact while clicking outside

Tags: jquery, html

I'm making an onscreen keyboard so I need to keep the focus of the activated textarea intact while clicking on the onscreen keyboard buttons.

I tried

```
$("#keyboard li").on("click",function(){
    // [#keyboard li] is the keyboard button
    $("#textarea").focus();
});
```

on clicking keyboard buttons but it's resetting the focus and pointer.

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by *"resetting the focus and pointer"*?

Comment: it means the textarea loses focus and then again gains focus in a blink